In CypressUnable to read data in the table
I have a table and I am trying to read the text in that  1st row 3rd column
But in the log I am getting empty string
Please help.
cy.get('tbody tr').eq(1).find('td').eq(3).then((td) =>{
const Text = (td.text());
cy.wrap(Text.trim()).as('cellText');
cy.log(Text)
console.log(Text)
}



Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Actually your code is working just fine. I made a small table with two rows (since cy.get('tbody tr').eq(1) gets the 2nd row) and four columns (since .find('td').eq(3) gets the fourth column).
I mention the exact location because it's easy to forget that .eq() is zero-based, and maybe you just targeted the wrong position.
Here is the sample table
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
      <td>three</td>
      <td>four</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

Here is the test and the passing log
cy.get('tbody tr')
  .eq(1)
  .find('td')
  .eq(3)
  .then(td => {
    const Text = td.text()
    cy.wrap(Text.trim()).as('cellText')
    cy.log(Text)
    console.log(Text)
  })


Using .then() to defer enqueuing commands
When you wrap commands in a .then()  callback function, it tells Cypress not to add them to the queue until the previous commands have run.
It's not necessary to use an alias when the .then() is in the same chain as the query.

Your issue is related to the synchronous/asynchronous nature of JS vs. Cypress. Gleb has an article specifically on why cy.log isn't working as you'd expect. The tl;dr is that Cypress queues it's commands before the value of Text is set. Instead, try using cy.invoke() to capture the text value and then storing it in an alias.
cy.get('tbody tr').eq(1).find('td').eq(3).then((td) =>{
  cy.wrap(td).invoke('text').as('cellText');
  cy.get('@cellText').then((text) => {
    cy.log(text);
    ... // other commands here.
  });
});

